# How do I get the current dir and assign it to a variable in linux

Tags: c++, linux, unix, getcwd

I new to program, currently I followed pwd tutorial and came out the code below. 
I need to assign a variable to hold the current directory, and join it with other file as below.

```
#include <unistd.h>
#define GetCurrentDir getcwd

main (
uint port,... )
{
  char buff[FILENAME_MAX];
  GgetCurrentDir(buff, FILE_MAX);

  FILE * fpointer ;
  fpointer =fopen(buff+"/config_db","w"); //here 
  fclose(fpointer);
}
```

Comment: Is that a typo for `GgetCurrentDir`?

Comment: Looks like [you need a good C++ book](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/388242/the-definitive-c-book-guide-and-list), instead of "online instruction".

Comment: Your code already does exactly what you describe. Unclear what you're asking.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Wiki Part**

In C++17, you are looking for `filesystem`:

```cpp
#include <iostream>
#include <filesystem>
namespace fs = std::filesystem;
int main()
{
    std::cout << "Current path is " << fs::current_path() << '\n';
}
```

See [cppreference filesystem](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/filesystem/current_path)

In linux API, you are looking for `getcwd`:

```cpp
#include <string.h>
#include <unistd.h>

#include <iostream>

int main() {
  char buf[1 << 10];
  if (nullptr == getcwd(buf, sizeof(buf))) {
    printf("errno = %s\n", strerror(errno));
  } else {
    std::cout << buf << std::endl;
  }
}
```

See [linux man page getcwd](https://linux.die.net/man/3/getcwd)

**Your Part**

What you did wrong is that you cannot concatenate `char *` or `char []` with `+`.
You should try `strcat` from `<cstring>` or apply `+` after casting it
to `std::string`.

```cpp
#include <unistd.h>
#include <cstring>

#include <iostream>

#define GetCurrentDir getcwd

int main() {
  char config_db_path[1 << 10];
  GetCurrentDir(config_db_path, sizeof(config_db_path));  // a typo here

  strcat(config_db_path, "/config_db");
  // concatenate char * with strcat rather than +

  FILE* fpointer = fopen(config_db_path, "w");
  fclose(fpointer);
}
```

Comment: what about linux? filesystem is for windows right?

Comment: @Alois `std::filesystem` is for compilers that support `c++17`, no matter what platforms.

Comment: Thanks @tigertang3. The previous error solved, but I have these errors now: PortSelection_main.c:22:5: warning: first argument of ‘int main(uint, ...)’ should be ‘int’ [-Wmain]
 int main (
     ^~~~
PortSelection_main.c:22:5: warning: ‘int main(uint, ...)’ takes only zero or two arguments [-Wmain]
PortSelection_main.c:22:5: warning: ‘int main(uint, ...)’ declared as variadic function [-Wmain]

Comment: you need to take a look at the template of c main function. uint should not be the 1st argument